# LibreOffice не открывает файлы с русским названием

Tags: locale, kubuntu, libre-office

При попытке открыть через LibreOffice Writer .doc-файл с русскоязычным названием появляется ошибка с что такого файла не существует с вопросительными знаками вместо названия файла. Подумав что это проблемы с кодировкой я перегенерировал локали `locale-gen` , что не помогло, как и попытка явно установить локаль `localectl set-locale LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` . При этом у меня почему-то отсутствует файл `locale.conf`, есть только `locale.alias` и `locale.gen` .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла перегенерация и перенастройка локалей:

`sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, имена открываемых файлов имеют кодировку CP1251.

Можете попробовать следующее:

```
apt install convmv

convmv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 --notest <path>/*
```

Warning! Преобразование коснется всех файлов целевого каталога.
Если кодировка имени файла кривая, то указать имя файла как параметр команды convmv в командной строке может и не получиться, поэтому и обрабатываются все файлы каталога.